# Работа с Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Хочу задать вопрос по поводу `Firebase`, а именно сохранение данных в БД `Firebase`. 
Насколько я понимаю: что как только данные сохраняются в БД Firebase, то они сразу отправляются на сервер и `Firebase` обновляет данные на всех устройствах, у которых установлено данное приложение. Что происходит, когда пользователь находится оффлайн, все данные пропадают? и юзер не может больше пользоваться приложением? Как решаются конфликты? Например, пользователем на одном устройстве удалил какие-то данные будучи оффлайн, а другой пользователь вносил изменение в эти данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как только обновляются данные в FireBase (и если вы использовали ValueEventListener), то у пользователя, который в этот момент работает в приложении произойдет обновление и он это увидит. Когда пользователь находится в оффлайн, все данные продолжают сохраняться в Firebase (только пользователь об этом не знает). Пользователь может по прежнему пользоваться приложением даже в оффлайн, как сказано в [документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). Если кто-то внес изменения в базу, то изменения произойдут сразу, а кто подключится из оффлайн, то есть станет онлайн, найдет нужную ветку и уже удалит эти данные. Так что другие пользователи не увидят ветку с этими данными из базы. 
П.С. что же у вас за данные, что пользователь их может удалить, а другой может их при этом менять? Может лучше сделать их личными - кто захотел удалил, поменял. А основные данные сделать доступными только для чтения большинству.